# How to have SBT re-run only failed tests

Tags: scala, unit-testing, sbt, scalatest, scalacheck

Is there a way to have SBT re-run only the tests that have failed in the last run of the test suite? For example, if I run `sbt test` and 3 out of the 20 tests I run fail, is there any command I can run to have SBT just re-run those 3 tests that fail?

Specifically I am using Scala Test and Scala Check for the tests I am running through SBT.

Comment: Try `test-quick` http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/docs/Detailed-Topics/Testing.html#test-quick

Comment: That seems to work for the ScalaCheck tests, but not for the Scala Test tests.

Comment: Actually, I tried it again and noticed that it rather just ignores all of the ScalaCheck test event the ones the fail.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are using the latest version of sbt simply run sbt testQuick.

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Testing.html

Comment: Running `sbt testQuick` does not work, as it re-runs all of the tests in a set of Scala Test tests when at least one of them fails. Additionally it ignores all ScalaCheck test whether they failed or not.

Comment: I don't believer there is a way to rerun all failed tests inside a suite without it running the whole test suite.  Also, you will need  to perform the ScalaCheck tests inside a ScalaTest to get those to rerun along with the ScalaTests.  Here is a decent example of how to do that.  http://sanj.ink/posts/2016-07-06-how-to-run-scalacheck-from-scalatest-and-generate-html-reports.html

Comment: I'm using sbt version 1.3.3 and sbt testQuick did not work for me. What worked was to go to the sbt shell and run `testOnly` with the name of the test classes which were failed. Example : `testOnly clients.MyClientSpec`